# ExpressJwt is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, jwt, express-jwt

I'm trying to write user authorization middleware. I use this function to validate and verify authorization later on.

I have done yarn add express-jwt.

**auth.js code:**

```
const SECRET = 'secret-message';

const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
const expressJwt  = require('express-jwt');
const compose = require('composable-middleware');

function sign(user) {
    return jwt.sign({
        _id: user._id,
    }, SECRET, {
        expiresIn: 60 * 60
    });
}

function sendUnauthorized(req, res) {
    console.log(req.headers.authorization);
    console.log(req.user);
    res.status(401).json ({ message: 'Unathorized' });
};

const validateJwt = expressJwt({
    secret: SECRET,
    fail: sendUnauthorized,
    getToken(req) {
        if (req.headers.authorization && req.headers.authorization.split(' ')[0] === 'Bearer') {
            return req.headers.authorization.split(' ')[1];
        } else if (req.query && req.query.access_token) {
            return req.query.access_token;
        }
        return null;
    }
});
```

**And the error is:**

```
const validateJwt = expressJwt({
                    ^

TypeError: expressJwt is not a function
```

I'm stuck on this error and can't go any further. I really need some advice.

Answer (score 3):

As the error says, `expressJwt` is not a function. The logical next step would then be to check what it *is* instead, and at the same time to recheck your assumption of it being a function (why do you think that?) and looking for sources for that, for example by checking the docs of the package.

You will find that a) it's an object with `{ expressjwt: <some function here> }`, and b) that the [docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-jwt) show an example that uses destructuring (`var { expressjwt: jwt } = require('express-jwt')`) which you don't do.

Both of these findings should point you to the fact that your assumption of the module's default export being a function is wrong and it's instead an object with property `expressjwt` which is the function you are looking for, so you could fix your code by using destructuring on the import as follows:

```js
const { expressjwt: expressJwt } = require('express-jwt');
```

(Alternatively, using `expressJwt.expressjwt(...)` would have worked too, of course, but I think it looks quite ugly and is unnecessarily verbose.)

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! Yes, I have read the docs and looked at the examples. Unfortunately, using destruction doesn't help. The error is still the same.

Comment: My fault, I misread `expressjwt` as `expressJwt` in the docs.

Comment: Please see my edit. (However, again, this should be apparent from looking at what the object contains, that's what I did now too to find my mistake.)

Comment: Yes, indeed, that helped. Thank you so much for the explanation, I realized my mistake. You're a magician! :))